# System.IO.IOException: Too many open files when using a background NSUrlSessionUploadTask

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Folks,

I'm having an issue with my application that is affecting the users in the field pretty heavily and I'm in need of some help. For context: users in the field receive work tickets and must respond to them with certain codes and information after they've worked said ticket. Their company, for any given response, may require a picture (sometimes pictures) to be uploaded. When the user takes a picture, it's saved to a directory in `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments`. When the user chooses a picture from their gallery, it/they is/are extracted as an object of the class `AssetResult` which has an `Image` property that is then turned into `NSData` with this statement: `NSData data = i.AsJPEG(new nfloat(0.8));` and it is subsequently saved with this statement:  `data.Save(picturesPath, true);`

I'm using, as stated in the title, an `NSUrlSession` with the `NSUrlSessionConfiguration.CreateBackgroundSessionConfiguration(string identifier)` method. The codefile containing the `NSUrlSession` code is named `UploadWrapper`; I do a simple `UploadWrapper upload = new UploadWrapper("PolarisPicture")` with `"PolarisPicture"` as the session identifier.

Here is my code/constructor for the configuration and instantiation of my NSUrlSession:

```
    public UploadWrapper (string identifier)
    {
        using (var config = NSUrlSessionConfiguration.CreateBackgroundSessionConfiguration(identifier))
        {
            config.HttpMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 10;
            config.TimeoutIntervalForRequest = 600.0;
            config.TimeoutIntervalForResource = 120.0;
            config.AllowsCellularAccess = true;
            bgSession = NSUrlSession.FromConfiguration(config, new UploadDelegate(), new NSOperationQueue());
        }
    }
```

Here is the method used to kick off the `NSUrlSessionUploadTask`:

```
    public void PrepareUpload(string filename, string database, int num, string member, string org, string ticket, string locator, string folder)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PrepareUpload called...");

            //var file = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "PolarisPictures2/IMAGE.jpeg");
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments));
            Console.WriteLine(filename);
            var boundary = "FileBoundary";
            string webApiAddress = "OURWEBAPI";
            NSUrl uploadHandleURL = NSUrl.FromString(webApiAddress);
            var bodyPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "BodyData" + num + ".tmp");
            NSMutableUrlRequest req = new NSMutableUrlRequest(uploadHandleURL);
            req.HttpMethod = "POST";
            req["Content-Type"] = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
            req["Filename"] = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename);
            req["database"] = database;
            req["folder"] = folder;
            req["member"] = member;
            req["org"] = org;
            req["ticket"] = ticket;
            req["locator"] = locator;
            Console.WriteLine(req["Filename"]);
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(bodyPath))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(bodyPath);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Building the string...");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
            sb.AppendFormat("--{0}\r\n", boundary);
            sb.AppendFormat("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"database\"\r\n\r\n");
            sb.Append(String.Format("{0}\r\n", database));                                     // Add database param
            sb.AppendFormat("--{0}\r\n", boundary);
            sb.AppendFormat("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"member\"\r\n\r\n");
            sb.Append(String.Format("{0}\r\n", member));                                       // Add member param
            sb.AppendFormat("--{0}\r\n", boundary);
            sb.AppendFormat("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"org\"\r\n\r\n");
            sb.Append(String.Format("{0}\r\n", org));                                          // Add org param
            sb.AppendFormat("--{0}\r\n", boundary);
            sb.AppendFormat("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"ticket\"\r\n\r\n");
            sb.Append(String.Format("{0}\r\n", ticket));                                       // Add ticket param
            sb.AppendFormat("--{0}\r\n", boundary);
            sb.AppendFormat("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"locator\"\r\n\r\n");
            sb.Append(String.Format("{0}\r\n", locator));                                      // Add locator param
            sb.AppendFormat("--{0}\r\n", boundary);
            sb.AppendFormat("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"folder\"\r\n\r\n");
            sb.Append(String.Format("{0}\r\n", folder));                                       // Add folder param
            sb.AppendFormat("--{0}\r\n", boundary);
            sb.AppendFormat("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"{0}\"\r\n", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename));
            sb.Append("Content-Type: application/octetstream\r\n\r\n");
            var fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
            using( var writeStream = new System.IO.FileStream(bodyPath, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, System.IO.FileShare.Read) )
            {
                writeStream.Write(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(sb.ToString()), 0, sb.Length);
                writeStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
                Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
                sb.Clear();
                sb.AppendFormat("\r\n--{0}--\r\n", boundary);
                writeStream.Write(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(sb.ToString()), 0, sb.Length);
                writeStream.Close();
                writeStream.Dispose();
            }
            sb = null;
            fileBytes = null;
            var uploadTask = bgSession.CreateUploadTask(req, NSUrl.FromFilename(bodyPath));
            uploadTask.TaskDescription = filename;
            Console.WriteLine($"New TaskID: {uploadTask.TaskIdentifier}");
            uploadTask.Resume();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
```

This method is called each time in a `foreach` loop that iterates through the currently attached pictures. After this `foreach` finishes, `upload.Finish();` is called, which is nothing more than calling the `FinishTasksAndInvalidate()` method of the underlying NSUrlSession object:

```
            foreach (var att in currTick.Origin.GetAttachedFiles(currTick))
            {
                upload.PrepareUpload(att, info.Database, 0, currTick.Fields["Member"], currTick.Fields["Org"], currTick.Fields["Ticket"], info.FirstName + " " + info.LastName, folder);
                index = index + 1;
            }
            upload.Finish();
```

with `att` being the path of the "attached" file.

Finally, here is my `DidCompleteWithError()` delegate method and the method that it calls inside if the upload was successful without error:

```
    public override void DidCompleteWithError(NSUrlSession session, NSUrlSessionTask task, NSError error)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("DidCompleteWithError TaskId: {0}{1}", task.TaskIdentifier, (error == null ? "" : " Error: " + error.Description)));

        if (error == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Deleting the picture copy since the upload succeeded");
            DeletePictureCopy(task.TaskDescription);
            task.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

`DeletePictureCopy();` is used to delete the local copy of the picture in order to save space:

```
    public void DeletePictureCopy(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(path);
            Console.WriteLine("We deleted the copy of the picture successfully!");
        } catch( Exception ex )
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

What could be causing `System.IO.IOException: Too many open files` here? This is the line that, every single time, the `PrepareUpload()` method trips up on:

`var fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);` (seen in the code above)

I can't, for the life of me, figure out why this is happening. I even close the `FileStream` used to write the bytes inside of the `using` just to make sure that it gets closed.

This issue happens after the user has uploaded 3 to 4 pictures. I have never encountered this issue on the first or second picture. Never.

Is the `NSUrlSessionUploadTask` closing the file(s) after a delay? Is the garbage collector not properly disposing of the files, even after I've manually done so?

I just cannot find the solution to this and would appreciate any amount of help or guidance.

Thanks.

Comment: TL;DR, but NSURLSessionUploadTask already creates a temp copy of the data/file that you are uploading... How many files are attached via your foreach statement?

Comment: @SushiHangover -- This is because all that `AssetResult` contains is its `UIImage`. I suppose I could store those images in an array and convert them to byte arrays in order to write them into the HTTP request, but I'm not sure that would remedy the problem. There can be anywhere between 1 and 10 images for each ticket. The maximum selectable from the gallery using the plugin that I'm using, ELCImagePicker, is 15.